# Parse JSON data, and then pass all its values to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building this website: http://collections.design

The way it works is by reading all tools data from a JSON, using jQuery (I don't know much javascript). Then, you can click on an item and a side panels opens with further information. But there's a lot of repeated code, so I'm trying to optimise it a bit.

First I parse the JSON:

```
// The data source
var data_source = "../data/tools/tools.json";

// Parsing the JSON
$.getJSON(data_source, function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {

    // And I'm storing all of its values in variables, to make them easier to read:
    var name = val.availability.name;
    var linux = val.os.linux;

    // Then I'm using all that to render each item on screen
    …

  });
});
```

Each of the items has a button that calls another function to create and open the side panel. The side panel reuses that item's data from the JSON. This function to create the side panel is using the `name` variable as parameter, but then inside is parsing the JSON again to get the rest of the values it needs.

**My question is:**

How can I "encapsulate" all variables when I do the JSON parsing, then pass it as a parameter to the other function; and finally, individually read each of those values in the other function?

I tried working with arrays. But didn't manage it to work, also keeping in mind that I'm trying to simplify things, not repeat myself, and keep short names…

Maybe I'm asking too much, but any pointers or links to doc will be appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working fiddle. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of doing this.

1) Save the JSON data outside the scope so you can reuse it and pass the index of the data you want.

Something like this

```
// The data source
var data_source = "../data/tools/tools.json";
var all_data;

// Parsing the JSON
$.getJSON(data_source, function(data) {

  all_data = data;

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {

    $('.button').on('click', function() { callToOtherFunction(key) }) 

  });
});

function callToOtherFunction(key) {
  console.log(all_data[key]);
}
```

2) As Sam Axe said, pass the data directly to the function

```
// The data source
var data_source = "../data/tools/tools.json";

// Parsing the JSON
$.getJSON(data_source, function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key,val) {

    $('.button').on('click', function() { callToOtherFunction(key) }) 

  });
});

function callToOtherFunction(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj5yf0r8/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is helpful. I'm also thinking of using variables in the first part, such as `description = val.basic_info.description;`-- is there a way for the other function to use that variable, or should I just use `val.basic_info.description` itself again? I was thinking of this mostly to keep names and references shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The data is already "encapsulated" in the `data` object.  Pass that object to the function that you want to use the data in.

You could always construct a new object - but what's the point - it's already in the `data` object.

Comment: But each tool has several of this `val.os.linux` in the JSON file, grouped in sections like `features":{ … }` etc. -- How can I pass all of the tool's values to the other function?

Comment: This is what I meant above: http://collections.design/data/tools/tools.json

Comment: Oh sorry, not the `val` object, but the `data` object.  You can just pass the data object around.